# count_if implementation - C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, templates

I am trying **myself** to create the generic function `count_if()`
(so I don't have to depend on the inclusion of `<algorithm>` by the STL).

This is my code:

```
template <class InputIterator, class Pred>
int count_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Pred pred) {
  int count = 0;
  while(first != last ) {
    if(pred(*first)) ++count;
    ++first;
  }
  return count;
}
```

I am trying to use this function as the predicate:

```
bool size_more_than_10(std::string val) {
  return val.size() > 10;
}
```

Problem: my predicate works with `std::string`, but when I dereference the iterator I get a `char` type, and a compilation error:

```
error: could not convert ‘__it.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator*<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >()’ from ‘char’ to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’
  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
```

This is my `main` (where I call `count_if()`):

```
int main() {
    std::string s;    
    std::getline(std::cin,s);
    std::cout<<"count: "<<count_if(s.begin(),s.end(),size_more_than_10);   
    return 0;
}
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: How do you call your `count_if` function with your predicate?

Comment: I am going to ad it in the post to add more info, thanks

Comment: You need to make your predicate accept whatever `*first` gives you.  That is how the standard one works.

Comment: you are iterating over characters not over a string.

Comment: Can you give an example? If `s == "hello"`, then what do you expect count_if to return?

Comment: When you iterate over `std::string`, you get every single character in this string, in order. You can't get a string from iterating over a string.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler false because "hello" has less then 10 characters.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen That's right but, so, how can I use count_if method with strings?

Comment: So why not simply call `s.size()` or `std::size(s)` ? And compare `s.size() >= 10` ?

Comment: To read the size of the string you don't need to iterate over it, do you? You should think of predicate that can be applied to each and every char. For example, `isLowercase(char c)`, then, your `count_if` function returns how many chars in string are lowercase.

Comment: Well, what do you want to count?  Checking of the size is more than 10 doesn't need any counting to happen.  You just check it with a function like you did. Now if you want to count how many characters of a certain type are in the string then `count_if` with a suitable predicate would be appropriate.

Comment: @lbat "how can I use count_if method with strings?" you need to use it with iterators from container that has strings in it, not a string itself - string is a container that has chars in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this algorithm incorrectly.
Your usage causes iteration over characters and predicate accepts string.

Here is [working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U8byKIH9dKdoSYc2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <class InputIterator, class Pred>
int count_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Pred pred) {
  int count = 0;
  while(first != last ) {
    if(pred(*first)) ++count;
    ++first;
  }
  return count;
}

bool size_more_than_10(std::string val) {
  return val.size() > 10;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << count_if(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), {}, size_more_than_10) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```